# JDOM SAXBuilder - assume CDATA for specific tags

Tags: java, xml, cdata, jdom

I'm using org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder to parse an input stream (XML file) into a JDOM document.

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(JavaScriptParser.class.getName());
org.jdom.Document document = builder.build(stream);
```

There are specific tags in my XML stream whose content within the tag must be treated as CDATA.

Example:

```
<text><![CDATA[ Any text... ]]></text>
<javascript><![CDATA[ function doSomething(){} ]]></javascript>
```

Currently the above examples will parse. What I have been trying to do for two days is try and extend the org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner so the following examples will parse the same as above.

Example:

```
<text>Any text...</text>
<javascript>function doSomething(){}</javascript>
```

Below is what I currently have. `scanCDATASection()` is copied from the parent implementation with only the `fEntityScanner.scanData("</javascript>", fStringBuffer)` line changed to look for my end tag instead of the double closing brace. It's hard for me to identify what the issue is, but I believe `EntityScanner.scanData("</javascript>")` isn't working correctly because I never get into the "if" statement. Or the way I'm going about injecting a call to `scanCDATASection()` inside of `scanContent()` is causing issues. I have to imagine there is a cleaner and straight forward approach to accomplish this task. I have no experience customizing an XML Parser and every use of SAXParser in our application uses the default setup. Any suggestions/hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class JavaScriptScanner extends org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl
{
    private final XMLStringBuffer fStringBuffer = new XMLStringBuffer();

    public JavaScriptScanner()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected int scanContent() throws IOException, XNIException 
    {
        if ("javascript".equals(fCurrentElement.rawname))
        {
            scanCDATASection();
            setScannerState(SCANNER_STATE_CONTENT);
        }

        return super.scanContent();
    }

    protected boolean scanCDATASection() throws IOException, XNIException 
    {
        // call handler
        if (fDocumentHandler != null) {
            fDocumentHandler.startCDATA(null);
        }

        while (true) {
            fStringBuffer.clear();
            if (!fEntityScanner.scanData("</javascript>", fStringBuffer) || 
                    fStringBuffer.toString().contains("</javascript")) {
                if (fDocumentHandler != null && fStringBuffer.length > 0) {
                    fDocumentHandler.characters(fStringBuffer, null);
                }
                int brackets = 0;
                while (fEntityScanner.skipChar(']')) {
                    brackets++;
                }
                if (fDocumentHandler != null && brackets > 0) {
                    fStringBuffer.clear();
                    if (brackets > XMLEntityManager.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                        // Handle large sequences of ']'
                        int chunks = brackets / XMLEntityManager.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
                        int remainder = brackets % XMLEntityManager.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
                        for (int i = 0; i < XMLEntityManager.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
                            fStringBuffer.append(']');
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
                            fDocumentHandler.characters(fStringBuffer, null);
                        }
                        if (remainder != 0) {
                            fStringBuffer.length = remainder;
                            fDocumentHandler.characters(fStringBuffer, null);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < brackets; i++) {
                            fStringBuffer.append(']');
                        }
                       fDocumentHandler.characters(fStringBuffer, null);
                    }
                }
                if (fEntityScanner.skipChar('>')) {
                    break;
                }
                if (fDocumentHandler != null) {
                    fStringBuffer.clear();
                    fStringBuffer.append("]]");
                    fDocumentHandler.characters(fStringBuffer, null);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (fDocumentHandler != null) {
                    fDocumentHandler.characters(fStringBuffer, null);
                }
                int c = fEntityScanner.peekChar();
                if (c != -1 && isInvalidLiteral(c)) {
                    if (XMLChar.isHighSurrogate(c)) {
                        fStringBuffer.clear();
                        scanSurrogates(fStringBuffer);
                        if (fDocumentHandler != null) {
                            fDocumentHandler.characters(fStringBuffer, null);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        reportFatalError("InvalidCharInCDSect",
                                        new Object[]{Integer.toString(c,16)});
                        fEntityScanner.scanChar();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fMarkupDepth--;

        // call handler
        if (fDocumentHandler != null) {
            fDocumentHandler.endCDATA(null);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call `return super.scanContent()` in an `else` instead? (`if ("javascript".equals(fCurrentElement.rawname)) { ... } else return super.scanContent()`).
It might be doing twice the job.
I have always used the default XMLReader as well so my guess is just a wild one.